# Yii search CDbCriteria "$sort->attributes" is not sorting "<db column> as attempts"

Tags: php, sorting, yii, grid

I need a way to sort a grid by clicking the column header...

```
public function search() {
    $criteria = new CDbCriteria;
    $criteria->select = 'cac.id, cac.client_name, cac.phone, cd.code, t.outgoing_call_date, (SELECT count(id) FROM css_ataps_calls WHERE caller_id = cac.id AND start_date = current_date) as attempts;
```

Sorting Section

```
$sort = new CSort();
$sort->defaultOrder = 'cac.id';
$sort->attributes = array('client_id', 'attempts'=>array('asc'=>'attempts', 'desc'=>'attempts DESC'));
```

SGridView Code

```
array('name'=>'attempts',
      'type'=>'raw',
      'value'=>'$data->attempts',
      'htmlOptions'=>array('style'=>'width:15%;text-align:center;'),
      'headerHtmlOptions'=>array('style'=>'width:15%;')
),
```

Comment: Are you returning it via `CActiveDataProvider` ?

Comment: Why "$data->**attempts**" and "**'attempts'**=>array(..."?

Comment: @AndreyShatilov 
I have added the code section including "BOLD" indications, zzlalani has edited them as code sections... so the BOLD went off!

Comment: @zzlalani yes I am using `CActiveDataProvider`

Comment: Why are you creating a `new CSort` object and what do you do with that? You don't have to do that, as the dataprovider will automatically create the right `CSort` object for you.

Comment: can you show your `CActiveDataProvider` code as well?

Answer (score 1):

In model class:

```
public $attempts;
```

and

```
$dataProvider=new CActiveDataProvider('...', array(
    'sort'=>$sort),
));
```

and in view grid:

```
'columns'=>array(
    ...,
    array(
        'name'=>'attempts',      
        'htmlOptions'=>array('style'=>'width:15%;text-align:center;'),
        'headerHtmlOptions'=>array('style'=>'width:15%;')
    ),
 )
```

You may also need to update attributeLabels in your model to reflect the new custom field.